# How to get the correct result from the data transmitted by protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am programming in c # and need to receive third party data (bytes) . I only know that this data (bytes) is sent through protobuf-net, but I don't know what its structure(contract) is.

Because you don't know his data structure(contract) , you fail to get the data in the following way

ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize(ms);

I want to convert this data (bytes) to string, and I'm trying to use Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);, but the result is garbled.

How can I convert bytes to the correct data without knowing his structure(contract)?

Comment: Ask the third party for the contract.

Comment: If you can't do that, capture a few example packets and hopefully you can work out the structure from that. I don't know protobuf internals but I'd guess strings or byte arrays have a leading length, so hopefully you can spot those.

Comment: @Rup there are tools for doing it; [one here](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode), or Google's `protoc` tool has a "decode raw" option; it is a bit more involved and nuanced than formats like JSON or XML, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about `UTF8.GetString` - that won't help here; if you have a payload but no schema, then the best thing to do is to *find* the schema - by asking whoever provided the data. Your next best bet is probably to *reverse engineer* the schema from the payload, using a combination of [tools like protogen](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode), and knowledge of what the actual data represents (which only you have have; I can only guess).

The problem, fundamentally, is that the protobuf binary format is heavily overloaded; the exact same bytes can mean *very different things* depending on the context, which comes from the schema. However, I have often helped people reconstruct schemas for data to which they didn't have the definitions, so it can absolutely be done.

If you have difficulty doing this just from the linked tool, I can probably help more, but I'd need to *see the data*.

--
Decoding the payload in the comments, something like this should work - all identifiers (names) are pure guesswork:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name {get;set}

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public Bar Bar {get;set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Bar {
    // Note this could also be a decimal under
    // Compat level 300 in protobuf-net v3
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string A {get;set;}
    // Repeat for fields 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
}
```

Then

```cs
var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<Foo>(source);
```

Comment: such like that(base64): "CAQSB2x0Y19jbmMyThIFMjk4LjkiBTI5OS42KgUyODkuNTIOMzk5NTguMDg5NDk3OTg6ETExNzY4NTQ3LjQ4NDA5Nzk4QgYwLjAyNjFKBTI5OC43UgUyOTguOQ=="    Through your links, still don't get the right structure

Comment: @231243 k, I can try and take a look at that later; on mobile right now

Comment: Are you sure you don't get the right structure? Marc's protogen gives sensible output for that for me: varint, string then a sub-object containing eight strings.

Comment: I agree with @Rup - it looks fairly simple; see edit

Comment: If I have to accept more than one data, more than one structure, how can I determine the corresponding structure of each data. For example, one minute you have a structure A, the next minute you have a structure B, and the next minute you have a structure C or A or B... Random return A B C structure . . The only way to do that is to "try catch"?

Comment: @231243 you can't rely on any particular structure throwing; that's not how protobuf works - sometimes deserializing with the wrong structure will throw, and sometimes it will silently just... load garbage data; protobuf is designed such that you *know* what you're deserializing. There are ways of expressing scenarios like this inside protobuf, for example "oneof" which can be modelled via inheritance in protobuf-net, but if the code serializing the data didn't use one of those approaches: you're SOL (also: you need to kick whoever is producing this data for missing an opportunity)